# Multi Agent Systems

Tags: arduino-leonardo, processing-lang

In my project work, I have 3 robots with their own Arduino boards. Each robot has Infra Red Sensors, whose values I can read using its corresponding Arduino. The main thing however is that each robot must have every other Robots' values. Can anyone suggest me a suitable strategy? I tried using the Processing Software, using which I am able to read all the values from all the robots but sending them back to the robots is turning out to be a problem! It says ports are busy!
Any help would be great!

Comment: What do you mean when you say "Processing Software"?  What are you using to read the values from the robots?  Are you using more equipment then the 3 robots you described in your question?

Comment: This is just a guess, but I suspect you are using the robots to look for a single IR source.  And that you have not yet considered the need to locate the robots in space disseminate that information among all the robots.

Comment: Are you looking for a way for each robot to communicate parameters to its partners? (That sounds like things that are available on several commercially available swarm robots, using IR or optical LEDs and receivers on each robot.)

Comment: For example see [this robot (Thymio)](https://www.thymio.org/en:thymioapi) under "Local Communication". That's an open source robot so you might be able to get a look at the firmware for ideas.